# Knockout binding on foreach item not updating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using the click event on a button to set the value of an item that was generated using a `foreach`.

```
<table>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees">
   <a  data-bind="click:$parent.delete()">
..
```

in my delete function I am setting the value but it doesn't update the screen

```
 Delete :(emp) {
  emp.active=false;
}
```

When I create I am setting all the individual properties as observable but seems like they are not when in the foreach loop.

- Update

Employees is filtered.computed

```
var Employees=ko.computed(function() {
 return ko.utils.arrayFilter(AllEmployees(), function (empid) {
            return empid.ID == filter();
        });
```

Comment: I updated my answer with an edit that should help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get/set observables you need to call them like this:

```
var val = obj.prop(); //Getter
obj.prop(false); //Setter
```

One other issue you have is that you are using parenthesis in your click binding. Remember that Knockout bindings are just javascript, so it will actually execute that expression when it binds.

You need to get rid of those parenthesis or `emp` will be undefined initially.

### UPDATE:

I've updated this jsFiddle to include three filtered lists similar to what you have shown above. You can see that **using a filtered list via a computed has no bearing on how knockout handles the bindings**, and the UI updates seamlessly.

http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/ceRPK/

Comment: when I do that I get an error that says it doesn't have a method called active

Comment: Then `active` must not be an observable. I think we need to see a little more code in order to determine where the problem is. Can you create a jsFiddle or something that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I will see if I can create a fiddle... Could it be because it's filtered?
    var Employees=ko.computed(function() {
     return ko.utils.arrayFilter(AllEmployees(), function (empid) {
                return empid.ID == filter();
            });

Comment: @user2643709 - No the filtered list shouldn't interfere at all with observables and bindings. I've updated my fiddle to demonstrate that using a filtered list via a computed has no bearing on bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example, I was able to find the issue. It was a problem with how the array was initialized.

Answer (score 1):

To set an observable, you have to call it (since observables are implemented as functions):

```
emp.active(false);
```

Your method simply overwrites the observable.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout subscribes to the observable array, but not to each observable within that array.  If you want to subscribe to individual properties you need to subscribe manually by using myObservable.subscribe()

Knockout subscribes to the observable array, but not to each observable within that array.  If you want to subscribe to individual properties you need to subscribe manually using myObservable.subscribe()

**Edit**

If you are trying to have your computed keep track of what should be in your computed you can do so like this -

```
var allEmployees = ko.observableArray([my data goes here]);

var Employees=ko.computed(function() {
 return ko.utils.arrayFilter(allEmployees(), function (emp) {
            return emp.active === true;
        });
});
```

That works if active is not an observable property of each allEmployees().  If it is an observable just change that to -

```
var allEmployees = ko.observableArray([my data goes here]);

var Employees=ko.computed(function() {
 return ko.utils.arrayFilter(allEmployees(), function (emp) {
            return emp.active();
        });
});
```

Comment: Sort of... if you have a foreach binding and you set up individual binding within the template, then the UI will update when you change individual items. You shouldn't have to subscribe to individual items unless you are doing it purely in code.

Comment: Well, the way that he mentioned it is doing it purely in code...  http://jsfiddle.net/hTVs9/  Stick around and I can show you some stuff about Knockout.